# I am not able to switch to another Activity from a ListView activity

Tags: android, listview

I have 3 activities in my application.

1. Start activity(with a timer of 5 sec after that Menu activity appears)
2. Menu activity
3. Main activity

The Menu Activity has a listview adapter.
I want to get the Main activity after clicking an item form the list but it is not switching to Main Activity after clicking.
Here is my Menifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="THE APP"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".start"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter android:label="MAIN">
            <action android:name="androphlie.myfirst.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="MENU" >
        <intent-filter
            android:label="MENU" >

            <action android:name="androphlie.myfirst.MENU" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

The Menu.java is as follows

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
String classes[]={"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3","example4","example5"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}



@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String listitem=classes[position];
    try {


        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.androfile.myfirst."+listitem);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();
    }


}}
```

I am new to android and not able to find out the problem in code

Comment: Add log message for more details.

Comment: if you click on first item then it probably move to `MainActivity`

Comment: use onitemclicklistener instead of onListItemClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onListItemClick listener ,package name `com.androfile.myfirst` you entered is incorrect compared to manifest file `com.androphlie.myfirst`

Change
`Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.androfile.myfirst."+listitem);`

to
`Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.androphlie.myfirst."+listitem);`